# org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: WINDOW2 was not found

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
InputStream isXls         = new FileInputStream("machine_operator_report.xls");
HSSFWorkbook workbookOld  = new HSSFWorkbook(isXls);
```

Below is the exception stack trace,

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: WINDOW2 was not found
at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.<init>(InternalSheet.java:340)
atorg.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.createSheet(InternalSheet.java: 
157)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init> 
(HSSFWorkbook.java:359)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init> 
(HSSFWorkbook.java:405)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init> 
(HSSFWorkbook.java:386)
at Xls2Xlsx2.main(Xls2Xlsx2.java:235)
```

I have tried all the solutions provided in stack over flow for converting 
`HSSFWorkbook` to `XSSFWorkbook`, but I am getting the above exception when I executed the code. `HSSFWorkbook` which i want to convert to `XSSFWorkbook` contains graphs also.

It would be so helpful for me if you could help on this!!. Thanks

Comment: Where did this file come from? If you open it in Excel and do a save-as, does that fix it?

Comment: It does fix the problem but only with the sheets which are having data. But fails with the sheets which are having graphs. Basically this excel is downloaded from an application through selenium automation. I can't do save-as manually every time i run the automation job.

Comment: Could you raise an issue with POI team and include the xls that demonstrates the problem? https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/